# debian networking wpa_supplicant configuration error

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I did a base install of Debian Jessie. I wanted to connect the computer over wifi. First I downloaded `wireless-tools`, `wpa_supplicant` and it dependencies. I also changed the file in /`etc/network/interfaces` so it would connect to my home wifi network. I tried `ifup wlan0` but it didn't work.

The error: `dbus: could not request service name: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied Connection ":1.4"is not allowed to own the service "fi.w1.wpasupplicant1" due to security policies in the configuration file`

I did everything as root.

The file: `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid wifi-network
    wpa-psk lame-password
```

The file: `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel

network {
    ssid="wifi-name"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="lame-password"
}
```

Comment: What is your desktop environnement?

Comment: it is a base install of debian. That means: I don't have a desktop environment.

Comment: have you got the wifi driver installed?

Comment: firware realtek installed.

Comment: please add the output `iw dev` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`